# When will price of BTC go below 100$?

Tags: mtgox, exchange-rate

Currently the price of 1 btc is more than 300$ at the time i wrote this. But , I had sold 5 BTC when the price was at 130 $ . I planned to buy them back when the price declined. But it never did.

Can I expect the bitcoin price to go back to 100$? If yes when? (Just make a guess...)

Comment: Yeah I did a little research it looks like over a 1 000 0000 bitcoins (1/12 of the total circulation) have been stolen by hackers over the last 3 years https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=83794.0 As soon as the media prints this story it will crash below $100.

Comment: Currently, the total number of bitcoins in circulation are approximately 12.000.000.So, maybe you mean 1.000.000, not 10.000.000 bitcoins stolen. Moreover I highly doubt that the value of bitcoin will fall as soon as the heist history of bitcoin will be media notished.

Comment: Questions calling for guesses are not a good fit for this site.

Comment: Silkroad 2 has just launched so it wont fall back down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speculation is an entire category of its own, in spirit of giving you some useful information I shall direct you to the following:

Speculation board: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?board=57.0

Reddit Bitcoin Markets; http://www.reddit.com/r/BitcoinMarkets

BitcoinMarkets on freenode also for live discussion also.